# Widget. Как обновить только некоторые View в RemoteViews

Tags: android, виджет

Есть RemoteViews со списком. У списка есть шапка (не Header, а отдельный FrameLayout сверху в корневом layout'е) в которой справа есть ImageView. Нужно, что бы после нажатия на ImageView, на его месте, некоторое время отображался круговой ProgressBar, а потом снова ImageView. Как мне это сделать, что бы не пришлось обновлять весь RemoteViews со списком?

PS: Я смотрел такую штуку как ViewFlipper, думал сделать одну итерацию и вернуться на ImageView, но похоже в нем нельзя задать количество итераций смены View. Если Вы знаете способ как это сделать с ViewFlipper, это будет предпочтительный вариант.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C API 11 есть метод  AppWidgetManager.partiallyUpdateAppWidget, если не подойдет, то только полностью виджет отрисовывать.

Comment: Я так понял, что RemoteViews - это всего лишь инструкции, а не "раздутый" View. Так что я изменил видимость ProgressBar'а на VISIBLE, а видимость ImageView на INVISIBLE, а затем вызвал partiallyUpdateAppWidget для всех виджетов. Думаю,он просто берет инструкции из  RemoteViews и меняет видимость у существующих View. После загрузки списка в методе onDataSetChanged, посылаю intent к AppWidgetProvider и снова меняю видимость.

Comment: Все правильно, RemoteViews - это инструкция, как собрать вью на хосте.

Answer (score 0):

Расположите `ProgressBar` над `ImageView` (по оси z), и меняте их видимость. После нажатия на `ImageView`, делайте его невидимым, а `ProgressBar` - видимым. Через нужное время делайте наоборот.

Comment: Ммм... Вы описали очевидную последовательность действий, кэп) Я бы так и сделал) Вопрос состоял не в этом. Как мне реализовать то, что Вы описали, в widget. Я не могу просто так обновить в RemoteViews определенный View, когда он уже создан и показывается на home screen. Но если есть возможность это сделать, прошу поделиться информацией.

Comment: @VovanderBaby https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20remote%20view%20set%20visibility&es_th=1